# Is Mysql a database management system(DBMS) or a database server?

Tags: mysql, database-design, dbms

I can't differentiate DBMS, database server and database client. Mysql, for instance, has Mysql shell, Mysql workbench, etc. If Mysql is a DBMS, then are Mysql shell and Mysql workbench both database clients?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! `(R)DBMS` = `database server`. `MySQL Workbench` is a GUI client. `mysql` is a CLI client!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

? I can't differentiate DBMS, database server and database client.

DBMS: An Architecture for working with data.
Simplistically, think of MySQL, the *Product*.

Database Server: mysqld, the running, daemon process that does the actual work.

(That said, most people use these two terms *interchangeably*).

Database Clients: mysql (command-line client), MySQL Shell and mySQL Workbench.

> ... are Mysql shell and Mysql workbench both database clients?

Yes.